# Set a specific range on Erlang Ephemeral port selection for use in Docker

Tags: docker, erlang, port

Needing to limit ephemeral port selection to a specific range, so I can expose that range via docker expose. I've seen how to limit the total number of ports with an `+Q Number` emulator flag, but was wondering if there is a way to specify a range of port that can only be used. This port range would need to apply to both UDP and TCP ports. I'm targeting Alpine Linux as the OS would / could / should it be set at the OS level instead of the Erlang VM?

Answer (score 0):

Use erl kernal options {inet_dist_listen_min, First} and {inet_dist_listen_max, Last} which defines the First..Last port range for the listener socket of a distributed Erlang node.

e.g. erl -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 9000 inet_dist_listen_max 9010

More details at http://erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html

Comment: Is this just for the Erlang distribution ports? I need to limit all ports. For example if I want to open a UDP port with gen_udp:open(0), I want to ensure it is limited to a certain range. Not just Erlang node communication.